# VisualStudio - Android Emulator not starting

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

It used to work but suddenly it stopped, well suddenly means, my machine had some windows update, deinstalled VS2017 entrprise, installed VS2019 Pro.

After an entire day of trial and error a gave up. I started installing my machine from scratch.

Win 10 + HyperV + WindowsHypervisor platform
VS2019 PRO
Android SDK 8.1
Android SDK tools 26.1.1
Android SDK Platform Tools 28.0.0
Android Emulator 27.3.9

And still I cannot get the emulator working again.

I applied all steps from :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#hyper-v

1. Is hardware ok ?

Coreinfo v3.31 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 0000000A
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)

[image]

[image]

2. Install / Enable Hyper-V

[image]

3. Install Android stuff

[image]

[image]

4. Created a new Device

[image]

5. Start the device from device manager

And the following error appears.

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you try the factory reset for the emulator in android device Manager?

Comment: "A 64-bit Intel or AMD Ryzen CPU with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)." your i7 is too old for this (see the " - " in Coreinfo which means unsupported)

Comment: It did worked before. SLAT is a new pre-req ?

Comment: Yes. Did try the factory reset.

Comment: Unselect Hyper-V and the windows Hypervisor Platform in windows features, re-boot your computer, just use HAXM to accelerate Android emulators on Windows, If it works.

Comment: as Leon wrote, use HAXM instead of HyperV platform

Comment: @BrilBroeder Did you try that?

Comment: I need hyper-V so that is not a solution

Comment: You could try to enable the  Hyper-v but un-check the WHPX, if it works? If not work, You should change a better comptuer. If you want to use both of them.

Comment: Going to change computer :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your update.